# Подключение уже имеющихся комментариев вконтакте на сайт

Tags: вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Приветствую. Такой вопрос:

Можно ли подключить на сайт в качестве виджета имеющееся обсуждение в группе?
Или можно только создавать новые виджеты комментариев, а потом уже добавлять их?

Answer (score 2):

Точно не знаю, не пробовал. Но у виджета есть параметр `page_id` который как раз идентифицирует обсуждение. В [документации пишут](https://vk.com/dev/widget_comments), что по умолчанию он равен "контрольной сумме от `location.href`", не уточняя алгоритм.

Моя гипотеза: можно установить на сайт виджет, указав "правильный" page_id. Я бы попробовал несколько вариантов алгоритма вычисления контрольной суммы от URL группы, а потом, когда ни один не поможет (комментарии в виджете не появятся), написал бы с этим вопросом в техподдержку ВК : )

Comment: Насколько я понял из документации, page_id определяет страницу на своем сайте, разве нет? Например, можно выводить один и тот же блок коментов на каждой странице, указав одинаковый page_id/

Comment: page_id определяет контекст — какой "набор" комментов для него рабочий. Гипотеза состоит в том, что и внутри ВК используется некий уникальный page_id, который просто не показывается. А как его получить - вопрос только к техподдержке. [Задайте вопрос техподдержке](https://vk.com/support), они узнают у разработчиков. И, как решите, не забудьте здесь отписаться для будущих поколений : )

Comment: Ответ сапорта - нельзя. Хотя, я все же думаю что реализовать нечто похожее можно. Например, скопировать дизайн виджета и сами коменты + разсместить новый виджет. Ну это изврат уже)